# Override default SERVICE_NAME in init.ora

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, listener

I'd like to define several service names for my instance in such a way that users should not know the actual instance name. This is what I have done in my `init.ora`:

```
db_domain='company.com'
db_name='tdbket'
instance_name='tdbket'
service_names=tedab+ket.company.com, tedab.company.com, ket.company.com
```

By [definition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams227.htm#REFRN10194), the default value `DB_UNIQUE_NAME.DB_DOMAIN` of the `service_names` attribute should be overridden.

Though, the Listener still lists this default value:

```
Dienst "ket.company.com" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "tdbket", Status READY, hat 6 Handler für diesen Dienst...
Dienst "tdbket.company.com" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "tdbket", Status READY, hat 6 Handler für diesen Dienst...
Dienst "tedab+ket.company.com" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "tdbket", Status READY, hat 6 Handler für diesen Dienst...
Dienst "tedab.company.com" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "tdbket", Status READY, hat 6 Handler für diesen Dienst...
Der Befehl wurde erfolgreich ausgeführt.
```

Why?

Comment: `SERVICE_NAMES` are in addition to the database name, not instead of it. If users don't have local access to the machine, they won't be able to see the "tdbket" entry anyway. If they do have local access to the machine they'll be able to see the Unix processes for the DB anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behaviour.
As long as you don't have the default service in your tns_aliasses that are in use it should not be a problem.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not fully understand what you are trying to say. Phil's answer is quite helpful.

Comment: The database instance will always register it's db_unique_name. You asked: why? answ: it is the default behaviour, we can not [yet] change that.

Comment: Ok, this is clear now. I presumed that the default value is replaced when the parameter is defined.

Comment: yes, sometimes default is incorrectly called default ;-)

Comment: I've sent a comment on the parameter site at Oracle.